# Why can't I cd into any subdirectories of my home folder?

Tags: command-line, home-directory

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.1 in a terminal window. When I am in my home user directory like `/home/jeg#`, I cannot `cd` into any directories below this. For example, if I enter `cd downloads`, or `cd /home/jeg/downloads`, I get the message `No such file or directory`. But when I do a `ls` command it shows me all the directories and files below `/home/jeg`. I can go into any other directory, so why is this a special case?

Comment: You said first I cannot cd into any directory while at the end of your question you said I can go into any othe directory???

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 I don't think this is a duplicate, just a question with an inaccurate title. Editing to reflect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu is case sensitive (files and directories named with capital letters are different from those named in lowercase)

try `cd Downloads`

Answer (score 2):

All directories are case sensitive. The other directory that is confusing to many users is the desktop:

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

The tilde symbol `~` is shorthand for `/home/any_user`; in your case, `/home/jeg`. You can use it to jump from anywhere to `/home/jeg`. If, for example, you were in the directory `/etc/modprobe.d` and wanted to get to `/home/jeg/Desktop`, it is only necessary to type the command I listed above.

Finally, the hashmark `#` after `/home/jeg` in your question implies that you are running as root. One of the many safeguards in Ubuntu is that root privileges are granted sparingly and temporarily as root privilege allows modification of the system by, potentially, the person at the next desk, drive-by viruses, and more. I recommend you exit from root privileges and use `sudo` instead.